# Как добиться того, чтобы календарь datepicker всегда был под инпутом?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ui, datepicker

Использую Datepicker UI. Если окно браузера имеет такую высоту, что календарь не помещается под инпут, календарь отображается над инпутом. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы календарь появлялся ВСЕГДА под инпутом. Как добиться этого наиболее верным способом?

Answer (score 1):

Если поглядеть в исходный код jQuery UI, код, отображающий календарь, сперва получает координаты [простым расчётом из координат поля ввода и его высоты](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/datepicker.js#L777), но затем пропускает их через [`$.datepicker._checkOffset`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/datepicker.js#L876), чтобы календарь не выходил за края экрана. Так что, как вариант, можно просто изменить её содержимое, причём необязательно в самом коде jQuery UI, можно и переопределить функцию позже:

```
$.datepicker._checkOffset = function(_, offset){ return offset; };
```